# jQuery Validation - How to have error label that is generated appear at end of div

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a situation like this:

```
<div>
  <label>Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="email">
  <label>Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</div>
```

using the jQuery validation library (using all the defaults for validating), the email "error" label will be generated like this:

```
<div>
  <label>Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="email">
  <label>ERROR:|</label>
  <label>Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</div>
```

but my goal is to get it like this:

```
<div>
  <label>Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="email">
  <label>Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <label>ERROR:|</label>
</div>
```

How do I do this?

[jQuery validation library](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

**Edit:**  The issue I'm running into with simply appending the label from the invalidHandler event is that the label is not generated until after the invalidHandler event.

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an errorPlacement function in the validation library.

```
$('.inputForm').validate({
   ... settings ....
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.parent());
   },
   ... other settings ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just assign an Id to your main Div and then append the Error to that Div.
e.g.

$("div#divid").append("error");

Comment: I was doing something like this, but where do I fire this?  I thought I would do it from the invalidHandler but doesn't seem to work

Comment: @contactmatt you need to place this to the errorPlacement. Check http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Validation Plugin will always prepend the error label **unless** you add your own first. So...

```
<div>
 <label>Text</label>
 <input type="text" id="email">
 <label class="error" style="display:none"></label>

 <label>Text</label>
 <input type="text" id="name">
 <label class="error" style="display:none"></label>
</div>
```

Be sure to set the class to be the same as the plugin is using and to hide the element by default.